# How can I receive a mp3 file from client App android to play framework?

Tags: java, android, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to make an application that sends an mp3 file to a server and save it in disk. But I'm having trouble finding information on how to do this, I just found this client code and now I need to implement the server, I need to use the Play Framework to do the web service, can anyone give me a help in how to do this.

My client:

```
    public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE  = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    private String SongPath;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String existingFileName = SongPath;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        String responseFromServer = "";
        String urlString = "http://177.105.46.89:9000/uploadSong";
        try {
            //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName));
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
//            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=song" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // close streams
            Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            String str;
            while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
            }
            inStream.close();

        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getSongPath() {
        return SongPath;
    }

    public void setSongPath(String songPath) {
        SongPath = songPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to do a file upload: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaFileUpload

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't do the client like you did. You can use [async-http-client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client), or [Apache HttpClient](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-multipart-upload) or [Jetty HttpClient](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/http-client-api.html). They handle most of the complexity for you.

Comment: Thanks this help a lot